# #region directives lost indention when updating to Visual Studio 16.5.1

Tags: visual-studio, region

`#region` directives are losing their indention in my C# code in the update of Visual Studio to Version 16.5.1.

I could not find anything in Options to remedy that. Anyone else running into this and maybe has a solution?

Comment: In this particular case, an attached screenshot might be helpful to show the issue.

Comment: The #region and #endregion lines had the # in column 1 rather than indented as it had been. The problem seems to have affected only top leveI #region / #endregion lines that were delimiting public classes. So there are not that many to worry about. After I reindent them, the desired indenting stays put. So, it is mainly a curiosity.